# Repeatability: Previous check

Tags: repeatability

I want to evaluate the repeatability of measures for a force device (the same records consecutively at the same conditions with the same device). Is there some option to check how many measures are required?

A few may be due to chance or the error being very large; many are not economical and may also present variations that are not realistic for actual operation.